# Shifting breaks in the cut() R function

Tags: r, statistics, cut, data-processing, binning

I have series of values between 0 and 360 and I would like to cut them into groups several times where each time the bins shift a little. I'd like to do this in R programming language.

For example:

```
d = runif(1000, 0, 360)
dd = rnorm(1000)
l = 10
breaks <- seq(0 , 360, l)
binned <- cut(d, breaks = breaks, ordered_result = TRUE)
```

Next, I want to keep the bins the same size, l, but shift them by two units. This means that my breaks start at 2 and end at 362. However, when I cut the data my values between 0 and 2 are labeled as NA. This is because there is no group for them. To correct this I need to make the last break, the 362 value, be same as the start of the sequence. I was wondering how could this be done in R?

Comment: Does `cut(d, breaks = breaks + 2)` do what you want?

Comment: @ChiragAnand I believe your suggestion just answered my question. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Will post this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could conditionally add 360 to values below 2 when you apply `cut` the second time:

```r
new_binned <- cut(ifelse(d < 2, d + 360, d), breaks + 2)
```

This gives the correct bins with no `NA` values:

```r
levels(new_binned)
#> [1] "(2,12]"    "(12,22]"   "(22,32]"   "(32,42]"   "(42,52]"   "(52,62]"  
#>![7] "(62,72]"   "(72,82]"   "(82,92]"   "(92,102]"  "(102,112]" "(112,122]"
#> [13] "(122,132]" "(132,142]" "(142,152]" "(152,162]" "(162,172]" "(172,182]"
#> [19] "(182,192]" "(192,202]" "(202,212]" "(212,222]" "(222,232]" "(232,242]"
#> [25] "(242,252]" "(252,262]" "(262,272]" "(272,282]" "(282,292]" "(292,302]"
#> [31] "(302,312]" "(312,322]" "(322,332]" "(332,342]" "(342,352]" "(352,362]"

which(is.na(new_binned))
#> integer(0)
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want the labels to wrap back round again, and need to generalize this to any shift, you would be best writing a function to do it:

```r
cut_wrap <- function(data, lowest = 0, highest = 360, break_every = 10) {
  
  breaks <- seq(0, highest, break_every) + lowest
  x <- cut(ifelse(data < lowest, data + highest, data), breaks)
  if(lowest == 0) lowest <- highest
  last <- sub(",.*$", paste0(", ", lowest, "]"), tail(levels(x), 1))
  levels(x) <- c(head(levels(x), -1), last)
  x
}
```

This allows:

```r
d = runif(1000, 0, 360)

d2 <- cut_wrap(d, 2)

d4 <- cut_wrap(d, 4)

levels(d2)
#>  [1] "(2,12]"    "(12,22]"   "(22,32]"   "(32,42]"   "(42,52]"   "(52,62]"  
#>  [7] "(62,72]"   "(72,82]"   "(82,92]"   "(92,102]"  "(102,112]" "(112,122]"
#> [13] "(122,132]" "(132,142]" "(142,152]" "(152,162]" "(162,172]" "(172,182]"
#> [19] "(182,192]" "(192,202]" "(202,212]" "(212,222]" "(222,232]" "(232,242]"
#> [25] "(242,252]" "(252,262]" "(262,272]" "(272,282]" "(282,292]" "(292,302]"
#> [31] "(302,312]" "(312,322]" "(322,332]" "(332,342]" "(342,352]" "(352, 2]"

levels(d4)
#>  [1] "(4,14]"    "(14,24]"   "(24,34]"   "(34,44]"   "(44,54]"   "(54,64]"  
#>  [7] "(64,74]"   "(74,84]"   "(84,94]"   "(94,104]"  "(104,114]" "(114,124]"
#> [13] "(124,134]" "(134,144]" "(144,154]" "(154,164]" "(164,174]" "(174,184]"
#> [19] "(184,194]" "(194,204]" "(204,214]" "(214,224]" "(224,234]" "(234,244]"
#> [25] "(244,254]" "(254,264]" "(264,274]" "(274,284]" "(284,294]" "(294,304]"
#> [31] "(304,314]" "(314,324]" "(324,334]" "(334,344]" "(344,354]" "(354, 4]"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is a good suggestion however, by adding 360 to the values less than 2 will change my data values. I'd like to avoid for that to happen.

Comment: @EM823823 it doesn't change your data values at all. It creates a new vector which is passed to `cut` to give the desired answer. The values that are below 2 are now labelled as being in the (352, 362] bin, which is what I thought you wanted. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Your method might work, too. However, I'd wanted for the last value, 362, to be considered 2 so that the last interval would be (352, 2]. Like wrapping the x axis so that it ends where it starts. I believe just adding 2 to the breaks it's achieves what I wanted.

Comment: @EM823823 but that leaves the values between 0 and 2 as NA. I thought you didn't want that?

Comment: If you add the line `levels(new_binned) <- c(head(levels(new_binned), -1), "(352, 2]")` to my code above, you will get precisely the result you were looking for.

Comment: you are right about Chirag Amad's method, it does generate NAs and I don't want that. I somehow missed that and my program performed as needed making me think no GAs were generated. Thank you for pointing that out to me! How could your method be generalized? I'm gonna have to make several shifts, like start from 2, 4, 6, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`cut(d, breaks = breaks + 2, ordered_result = TRUE)` should do it.

Comment: Doesn't this leave values between 0 and 2 as `NA` though?